# Arduino Mega 2560, how get the board firmware version?

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to get the firmware my Arduino board uses but can't get it. My real problem is that I'm getting this error when uploading the blink example on my board:

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

I'm using fedora 16, kernel 3.3

What do I need to do to solve this?

Comment: What about modifying the upload baud rate or pressing the reset button before the upload?

Comment: Are you using the Arduino IDE?

Comment: By the way on linux, how do i know the firmware version of the board

Comment: Have you tried this on a Windows machine?  That would help you understand if the board has a problem, or your setup on Linux is the issue.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to find a windows machine and check it!!

Comment: @Julie in Austin, do u know how to find out the board firmware on linux??

Comment: @Noor: I'm not even sure what you mean by "board firmware".  The only things there are to "know" is the bootloader type and board.  You know it's an ATmega 2560, now you just need to know that it has the correct bootloader for that model of Arduino.  Getting the board to work on Windows will tell you that it has the correct bootloader installed.  For what it's worth, Linux seems to have a harder time talking to Arduinos at 115.2KBaud.

Comment: @JulieinAustin I think Noor means the Atmega 16AU or 8AU TX/RX to USB converter chip or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sketch that [detects chip signatures](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633) including taking an MD5 sum of the bootloader. Effectively, this gives you a signature of the firmware. Some known signatures are displayed as a known file name. For example:

```
MD5 sum of bootloader = FB F4 9B 7B 59 73 7F 65 E8 D0 F8 A5 08 12 E7 9F 
Bootloader name: optiboot_atmega328
```

You need another board (eg. a Uno) to run the sketch on.

Not that this will solve your overall problem (unless there is no bootloader at all).

You would also be told the fuse settings, so you could check for something like the "divide clock by 8" fuse being set.